# Landsat 8 QA band conversion error?

Tags: r, landsat-8

I downloaded Landsat 8 NDVI bands from the USGS (instead of calculating them myself). The QA band that came with has values different than I see in the Landsat 8 user guide.

Using R I did a quick `sort(unique(as.vector(image[[1]])))` and got these values:

`322 324 328 336 352 368 386 388 392 400 416 432 480 834 840 848 864 880 898 904 912 928 944 992`

Here is the actual QA raster. Guessing high values are clouds.

[image: LC080410292016030201T1-SC20191028014724 QA band for NDVI]

Comment: Looks like they're in binary: https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/land-surface-reflectance-code-lasrc-product-guide

Comment: ^ Specifically, Table 6-1

Answer (score 1):

The "pixel_qa" band is bit indexed. The following is an example of generating a 0-1 mask from the image using the R raster package.

See the product guide starting with Table 6-1 for more information:
https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/land-surface-reflectance-code-lasrc-product-guide

```
# Define path to pixel_qa.tif file.
pixelQaFile <- "path/to/pixel_qa.tif"

# Load the QA file into memory.
pixelQaData <- getValues(raster(pixelQaFile))

# Use bitwise and logical operator to identify cloud, shadow, and snow.
shadow <- bitwAnd(pixelQaData , 8) == 0  # shadow
snow <- bitwAnd(pixelQaData , 16) == 0  # snow
cloud <- bitwAnd(pixelQaData , 32) == 0 # cloud

# Combine the three mask elements. In the result, 0 is invalid pixel, 1 is valid pixel.
mask <- shadow * snow * cloud
```